# MySQL In result are NULL's when join left 3 tables

Tags: mysql, sql, join

I have problem with result when join 3 tables because I have in some place NULL a should be number or empty cell.

My tables in database:

```
    Table nr 1: rysunek

    id_rys | nazwa_rys   | nazwa_klienta | ...
    3      |01_116230_C0 |PHILIPS
    7      |11_002177_A0 |P&G
    20     |01_101854_B0 |MARS FOOD
    333    |None         |None

    ( + 7 columns which do not use in this query)
```

```
    Table nr 2: artykul

    id_art |id_rys |nazwa_art  | id_status | ...
    1      |3      |00_16_1234 | 1
    2      |7      |00_16_1235 | 3
    3      |7      |00_16_1236 | 0
    4      |333    |00_16_1237 | 0

    ( + 10 columns which do not use in this query)
```

```
    Table nr 3: statusy

    id_status |kod_status 
    1         |IA     
    2         |NC      
    3         |861
```

Mysql query looks like this:

```
 SELECT r.nazwa_klienta
      , r.nazwa_rys
      , a.nazwa_art
      , s.kod_status 
   FROM artykul a 
   LEFT 
   JOIN rysunek r 
     ON a.id_rys = r.id_rys 
   LEFT 
   JOIN statusy s 
     ON a.id_status = s.id_status;
```

And result looks like this:

```
    nazwa_klienta | nazwa_rys    | nazwa_art  | kod_status
    NULL          | NULL         | 00_16_1234 | IA 
    NULL          | NULL         | 00_16_1235 | 861
    P&G           | 11_002177_A0 | 00_16_1236 | NULL
    None          | None         | 00_16_1237 | NULL
```

I need to the result of query above look like this:

```
    nazwa_klienta | nazwa_rys    | nazwa_art  | kod_status
    PHILIPS       | 01_116230_C0 | 00_16_1234 | IA 
    P&G           | 11_002177_A0 | 00_16_1235 | 861
    P&G           | 11_002177_A0 | 00_16_1236 |    [empty cell]
    None          | None         | 00_16_1237 |    [empty cell]
```

How should looks like my query? I tried all join methods but none of them work.
Maybe I should change structure of my tables? I'm waiting for some suggestion from somebody... :)

Comment: So start with rysunek

Answer (score 0):

Left joins are going to create empty entries for your rysunek columns whenever there is no row in that table that matches artykul's. If you don't want them listed, then don't use an outer join between those two tables (I note you didn't list them in your desired output).

For the other NULLs, from kod_status, since it is a numeric column, pretty much your choices are: take the null; or turn it into a 0 with a COALESCE(kod_status,0), or cast the result to a string and turn its nulls into empty strings. There are command-line options in the mysql command-line tool (which your output appears to be from) (see http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/mysql-commands.html ) there may be a way to change how it outputs nulls if that would fit your use-model needs.

Comment: I exported and imported again data from artykul's and rysunek's tables and NULLs in nazwa_klienta and nazwa_rys disappeared.In kod_status I changed all 0 to 1 and add to my query "NOT LIKE '%1%'". I don't know if it is the right solution but for now form me is okay. Thanks for your answer.

Comment: Adding the NOT LIKE '%1%' is going to get rid of any kod_status that contains a 1 anywhere, not just the statuses that are 1's. (be careful)